# SQL select: summ all ratings for setups from users. Multiple setupratings in one table (SQL FIDDLE included)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a sql select running, but every time I try, I realize I'm definitely not made for this.

My setup is as follows.

I got 2 tables. One for gamers, where for example names are stored, and one in which users (user table not important) can vote for a setup (setup table also not important) of gamers.

So in the ratings table it is stored which user voted for which gamersetup (all with ID's), how many points the user gave and which setup he rated, because gamer can have multiple setups.

I've created a SQL Fiddle for you [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/facd0f/4).

Now I'm trying to get a list of all setups (attention to the different setups), ordered by the rating (here is important, that the SUM() is divided by the number of users who voted for this setup) DESC

I tryed something like this, but of course it doesnt work.
SELECT sum(gsr.gsr_rating), gsr.gsr_setup_id FROM gamersetupratings gsr JOIN gamer as g ON g.gamer_id=gsr.gsr_rated_id WHERE gsr_rated_id = (SELECT gamer_id FROM gamer)

My friend and I failed terribly, maybe you guys have more skill.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In yoru SQLFIDDLE You have an error from subselect 
If you need  more then a rows  for your match  you can use a in clause (or a join)

```
SELECT sum(gsr.gsr_rating)
 , gsr.gsr_setup_id 
 FROM gamersetupratings gsr 
 JOIN gamer as g ON g.gamer_id=gsr.gsr_rated_id 
 WHERE gsr_rated_id in (SELECT gamer_id FROM gamer)
```

Otherwise if you need  a single rows for subselect  you can use a limit 1

```
SELECT sum(gsr.gsr_rating)
   , gsr.gsr_setup_id 
   FROM gamersetupratings gsr 
   JOIN gamer as g ON g.gamer_id=gsr.gsr_rated_id 
   WHERE gsr_rated_id = (SELECT gamer_id FROM gamer order by gamer_id limit 1)
```

but you don't need  the subselect  you have alredy the value you need  in join on condition

```
SELECT sum(gsr.gsr_rating)
 , gsr.gsr_setup_id 
 FROM gamersetupratings gsr 
 JOIN gamer as g ON g.gamer_id=gsr.gsr_rated_id
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I'm looking for. It's not the aim to add all up, I got that already. I'm trying to get a list of all setups, ordered by the rating.

Comment: then   .. update your question add  a proper data sample and the overall add  your  expcted  result  ..not in word  but with data sample

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the distinct game IDs and what the average rating for each is. Unless I misunderstood, I think you should just be looking for the average for each gsr_setup_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(gsr_setup_id) as timesVotedFor,
AVG(gsr_rating) as rating,
GSR_SETUP_ID as setupID
FROM gamersetupratings
GROUP BY gsr_setup_id
ORDER BY rating desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting desired result by below query.

```
SELECT sum(gsr.gsr_rating) as gsr_rating, gsr.gsr_setup_id, 
     sum(gsr.gsr_rating) /count(gsr.gsr_rated_id) as sorting_value
    FROM 
    gamersetupratings gsr 
    JOIN gamer as g 
    ON g.gamer_id=gsr.gsr_rated_id 
    Group by gsr.gsr_setup_id
    Order by sorting_value desc
```

If you wish you can directly put that `sum(gsr.gsr_rating)/count(gsr.gsr_rated_id)` value in `order by` clause but for better understanding of the problem I just put like that